# Continuous time random walk.

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Consider a random walk $X_t$ in continuous time in $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that the walker expects an exponential time of rate $\alpha$ to jump to the right and an exponential time of rate $\beta$ to jump to the left.

Suppose $X_0 = 0$ and that $\alpha >\beta$.  I want to show that

$$\mathbb{P}\left(X_t < \frac{(\alpha -\beta)}{2}t\right)\leq Ce^{-Kt}$$

where $K$ and $C$ are constants.

My only question is:

During any time interval $t$, the displacement of the walk can be limited by a random variable $Y_t \sim \text{Poisson} ((\alpha-\beta) t)$?

I think so, but I can't justify it. If the answer is yes, I think I can solve it.

Comment: The number of jumps to the left during $[0,t]$ has a Poisson mass function with parameter $\beta t$. Here I am assuming the state space is the set of all integers (including negative integers).

Comment: Hi, Michael, you're right. I made some mistakes. First, the space of is $\mathbb{Z}$. Second, I wanted to say that during any time interval $t$, the displacement of the walk can be limited inferiorly by a random variable $Y_t \sim \text{Poisson} ((\alpha-\beta) t)$. I've already made the corrections above.

Comment: No, that bound doesn't hold in general. The displacement is exactly given by a Poisson($\alpha t$) minus an independent Poisson($\beta t$) but the difference of two independent (nondegenerate) Poissons is not Poisson. If you want to clean this up you will need to clarify what exactly "decays exponentially" is meant to mean. Do you mean only for large $t$? In that case you can adapt what I just said to say that the displacement is asymptotically $N((\alpha-\beta)t,(\alpha-\beta)t)$ distributed and then you're essentially done.

Comment: By contrast, if you want an estimate that has meaning for small $t$, then you'll need to get into the weeds of writing down the PMF of a difference of independent Poissons. This will require you to basically evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X=n) P(Y=n+k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hi, Ian, with exponential decay I meant that $\mathbb{P}\left(X_t < \frac{(\alpha -\beta)}{2}t\right)\leq Ce^{-Kt}$ where $K$ and $C$ are constants.

Comment: That can probably be achieved with CLT as I suggested, though if you want explicit $C$ and $K$ that hold for all $t$ then it is probably easier to just jump into the PMF calculation instead.

Comment: You can use (for any random variables $Right, Left$ and any constants $\alpha, \beta, \epsilon$): $$P[Right - Left \leq \alpha-\beta-2\epsilon] \leq P[Right \leq \alpha-\epsilon] + P[Left \geq \beta + \epsilon]$$ which holds even if $Left$ and $Right$ are dependent (which they are not).

Comment: Thanks, Michael